# Uncaught node.js Error, undefined symbol: _ZN2v811HandleScopeC1Ev

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-webkit, node-gyp, pouchdb

I am trying to use PouchDB with node-webkit. Which inturn is a node_module. What I could understand so far is that node-gyp is probably not compatible, trying to load the 3rd party node_modules(PouchDB).

note: I am also using nodejs virtualenv for node-webkit.

when I use `var PouchDB = require('pouchdb');` in the script the following error is thrown.

> Error: /home/manjunath/node/node_modules/pouchdb/node_modules/leveldown/build/Release/leveldown.node: undefined symbol: _ZN2v811HandleScopeC1Ev
>      at Error (native)
>      at Module.load (module.js:352:32)
>      at Function.Module._load (module.js:308:12)
>      at Module.require (module.js:360:17)
>      at require (module.js:376:17)
>      at bindings (/home/manjunath/node/node_modules/pouchdb/node_modules/leveldown/node_modules/bindings/bindings.js:76:44)
>      at Object. (/home/manjunath/node/node_modules/pouchdb/node_modules/leveldown/index.js:1:99)
>      at Module._compile (module.js:452:26)
>      at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:470:10)
>      at Module.load (module.js:352:32)
>      at Function.Module._load (module.js:308:12)

I find no way out of this, please help me !

Answer (score 0):

You have to use [`nw-gyp`](https://github.com/rogerwang/nw-gyp) to compile addons for use with `node-webkit`. See [this](https://github.com/rogerwang/node-webkit/wiki/Using-Node-modules#3rd-party-modules-with-cc-addons) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

PouchDB is actually really flexible when you're using node-webkit. Rather than using nw-gyp and all that jazz to get LevelDB running on the Node side of things, you can actually just include PouchDB in a `<script>` tag (as if you were writing a browser app) and it will use IndexedDB instead. (WebSQL is also available, if you want.)

You will probably have a much easier time with this solution than with the Node-style (i.e. LevelDB) solution. Just my hunch.